# High availability in Azure service bus and event grid integration

Tags: azure, events, service, grid, bus

I am working on a solution where messages posted in service bus topics will be passed as events in event grid and those events will be parsed by Azure functions and stored in Cosmos Db. From Db API layer (may be service fabric hosted microservices) will be used for displaying data in web ui. How do I design this for high availability? I am confused on how to design for HA in the service bus and event grid components.

Comment: Microsoft have specific guide lines around service bus https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters  and be aware of service-bus-dead-letter-queues. In this particular scenario Why do you need event grid ? You can directly trigger azure function using "service bus trigger" and store them in cosmosDB.

Comment: Thanks imran. Its a question for me as to what are the benefits of adding event grid to receive events from service bus. I see that in Microsoft documentation, it is told to use it after service bus.Thanks in advance